# Work with a local copy of the "master" SVN repo

Tags: svn, bash

at work, we have a SVN repo, which we access to thorugh http, like:

```
svn co http://user@machine/PATH
```

even at work and for some misterious reasons, teh connections between local machines and the repo machine are very slow, but the connection between home and work is almost impossible.

I wonder if I could do somethin like:

1- get a copy of the "master" SVN repo to my local machine
2- each time i make modifications etc, use

```
svn co http://user@MYLOCALmachine/PATH
```

instead of

```
svn co http://user@machine/PATH
```

3- when I am back at work, "merge" somehow all the modifications in my local repo to the master one.

Sorry, I am ewally new to SVN, any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is putting a band aid (which won't work anyway) on the real problem which is the slowness of your http connection - you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to sounds a lot like the distributed version control model. Subversion is not a distributed VCS, and thus can't really support the kind of functionality you're referring to - there can't be more than one "master", merges all have to go through the same server.

DVCS like git, mercurial, bazaar, et cetera on the other hand support exactly that kind of workflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subversion doesn't support such workflow.  It should be connected to server to commit stuff.
2. Distributed version control systems (like git, bazaar, etc), however, support such behavior.
3. Git has an interface to subversion (git-svn); it can send local commits to remote server only when you want it, not on each commit.
4. Use [git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679648/working-locally-with-git-when-main-repository-is-svn) to work with your subversion repository!
5. PROFIT!